# oneric-security apt source is missing?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-11.10

On apt-get on a 11.10 machine i'm getting:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80] 
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/multiverse/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/oneiric-security/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

Indeed, security.ubuntu.com has packages for other releases, but not 11.10.  What happened to them?

Answer (score 2):

It has reached [EOL status a year ago](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and therefore removed from the main repositories. Update the system as soon as possible to something supported.

Other than that, archives for old releases can be found [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/).